# How can I get a struct from a specific memory location?

Tags: c, memory, pointers

I have the memory location of a struct stored as an integer. How can I retrieve the struct stored at that location and make a pointer to the object at that location?

```
Structure object;
int memLocation = &object;

Structure objectCopy = (objectAtLocation) memLocation;
Structure *objectPointer = (pointerToLocation) memLocation;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `int`s instead of pointers is very bad form, going back even to the first edition of K&R.  So what you're doing is bad.  But assuming you have no choice...

if `Object` is a `Structure`, then `&object` is a `Structure *`.  So the proper un-cast is basically your line 3:

```
Structure *objectPointer = (Structure *) memLocation;
```

Comment: +1. For conversion between integers and pointers, always use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`.

Comment: I know that normally I should use a pointer, but I need to be able to control the location by byte manually.

Comment: How would line 3 look in an actual program?

Comment: Just updated my answer - you need to cast to a `Structure *`.

Comment: I am confused by your comment.  Pointers give an object's memory address at the byte level.  What can you do with `int`s that you can't do with pointers?

Comment: say I have float *a, then a+1 = a + sizeof(float)bytes. if int a = &floatObject, then a+1 = a+1 byte

Comment: If you want to work with the individual bytes of a floating-point number, the idiomatic way is probably casting the `float` to an `unsigned char *` of 4 elements and operating on the elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
int memLocation = (int)&object;

Structure *objectPointer = (Structure *) memLocation;
Structure object;
memcpy( &object, (void*)memlocation, sizeof( Structure ) );
```

Comment: hmm... just tried on mac mini with 10.6 - gcc said nothing. Try to cast to `(void*)` beforehand.

Comment: If he knows `memLocation` already points to a valid object, there's no need to use memcpy. `*(Structure*)memlocation` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The usual is a cast:

```
Structure *object = (Structure *)memLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Structure *objectPointer = (Structure *)memLocation;
Structure ObjectCopy = *objectPointer;
```